# How to convert a string to an integer in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, integer, int

I am trying to create a string from a variable in PowerShell. I want to display numbers as strings and not as integers.

I have tried putting [str] before my variable, like for string to integer ([int]), but that gave me an error. I also searched my issue but no one has asked a question like this.

The code in question is the "$jstr" line.

```bsh
for ($j = 0; $j -lt 1000; $j++)
    {
        $jstr = [str]$j
        $dot = "."
        $num = $jstr + $dot
        Write-Host $num, Get-Random -SetSeed $j
    }
```

I want the output to be something like "1. *Random number*", with 1 being the seed number and *Random number* being the number mapped to that seed,

Comment: the type accelerator for strings is ... `[string]`, not `[str]`. [*grin*]

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking. Title is "How to convert a string to an integer in PowerShell?" But, then in your post you state, "I want to display numbers as strings and not as integers." Do you want strings as integers or integers as strings?

Comment: Thank you Lee, I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways...

If you have a number expressed as a string, you can call `string`'s `toInt32()` method:

[image]

You can assign it to a variable with the type identifier:

[image]

However, this ONLY works if the string is ALL numbers (no non-numeric/non-hex characters).

If you want to go the other way (express an integer as a string), use the `toString()` method:

```
$integer.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
for ($j = 0; $j -lt 6; $j++)                                                                                          
{
  $rand = Get-Random -SetSeed $j
  "$j.$rand"
}

0.1866861594
1.42389573
2.365335408
3.688215708
4.1011161543
5.1334173171
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to get a list with the seed on the left, a dot, and then the random number. it uses the `-f` string format operator to place the numbers *and* to align the numbers in the allotted space. [*grin*]

```
$Start = 0
$End = 10
$SLength = ([string]$Count).Length

$RMin = 0
$RMax = 1e3
$RLength = ([string]$RMax).Length

foreach ($Number in $Start..$End)
    {
    "{0,$SLength}. {1,$RLength}" -f $Number, (Get-Random -SetSeed $Number -InputObject ($RMin..$RMax))
    }
```

output ...

```
 0.  607
 1.  602
 2.  997
 3.  636
 4.  143
 5.  839
 6.    6
 7.  404
 8.  536
 9.  394
10.  124
```